# Should web browser apps running in Windows 7 be tested on Windows 10 before migrating to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, browser, compatibility, migration

I am on a project where over 20,000 desktops will be migrating from Windows 7 to Windows 10. There has be a question as to whether or not it is necessary to test if a web browser app being access from Windows 7 needs to be tested to ensure it runs on Windows 7. The user base is currently at Windows 7. We want to avoid someone getting their desktop upgraded to Windows 10 and afterwards finding that the web app they used in Windows 7 does not run properly in Windows 10.

Some say it is not necessary because the apps are running on the server so no bearing on Windows 10. Other say it may be necessary because the web pages sent to the desktop may have been coded to use a custom feature of a specific browsers. Other say it may be necessary to test because the web page sent to the desktop may require a minimum version of a browser in order to support a certain version of java script.

I would like some feedback from the community, especially those who have already been through a Windows 10 migration, as to why is it necessary or necessary to test a web browser app for Windows 10 compatibility when migrating from Windows 7.
Thank you

Comment: It would be sheer madness to blithely migrate 20,000 users without testing for every eventuality.

Comment: Web based applications are platform and browser agnostic unless there is some very specific Microsoft related item hooked into them. The same websites I have created on older versions of macOS work fine on modern versions of any OS; macOS or otherwise. That said, for 20,000+ users if there is a concern, then create a test Windows 10 version of the desktop environment and test the web application. Better calm fears then say “Trust me!” in a case like this.

Answer (score 3):

For that number of users, you should set up one or two Windows 10 machines and test the applications.

Everything we used web-based that ran on Windows 7 runs also in Windows 10 (ticketing and other systems), but do test first and know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have been through such a migration.

Any web-based app that runs fine in Chrome or Firefox on Win7 will also work without issue on Win10. There is no need to test because pages in Chrome and Firefox cannot break out of the browser sandbox, even if they require plugins to work properly. Therefore, their behavior is standard across all platforms those browsers run on.

That just leaves Internet Explorer as the maverick.  *Generlly speaking* anything that runs inside Internet Explorer on Win7 will also work on Win10, but there are some exceptions. Some vendors' web-based apps *require* Internet Explorer in order to function. This is almost always because the app requires an ActiveX control that hasn't been ported to other browsers (and it usually hasn't been ported because it breaks the browser sandbox on purpose in ways the other browsers don't allow). These **will** need to be tested.

So here's the guideline to follow:

If an app you use works in Chrome or FF on Win7 -- even if you typically run it in IE -- it should work fine in Win10 (even if you might *need* to run it in Chrome or FF because it doesn't work right in IE on Win10).

If an app *requires* IE to work properly in Win7, then you'll need to test it thoroughly in IE on Win10 before you migrate.

Fortunately, IE's ActiveX plugin model is on the way out. Microsoft only keeps IE around on Win10 because there are so many vendors that used exactly this scenario. But those should all soon die an undignified death in the (hopefully) near future. Check with your vendors for upgrades.

One more thing:

If you run into this situation where a vendor app needs specific IE quirks in order to run, you should look into [IE Enterprise Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode). Enterprise Mode allows you to specifically tailor IE's behavior on a per-URL basis to overcome obstacles you may encounter with certain web-based apps thay only work right on certain versions of IE.